# Trying to Determine if MacBook Pro 2011 projects in 4:3 or 16:9 format during presentations

Tags: macbook-pro, keynote

The company I work for is hosting a corporate presentation next month. We have hired outside A/V services and he is asking me if I will be projecting in 16:9 or 4:3 and if we will need a 5k or 10k projector. From what I have found, I believe the 10k projector is necessary for the 16:9 aspect ratio.
Is there anyway to determine which aspect ratio my MacBook Pro 2011 (OS X 10.9.5) would project in?

Comment: Your native aspect ratio is 8 : 5. If you are using Keynote for Mac to present, click wide when picking your template, which can be blank. When being chosen as wide, it sets the ratio to 16:9.

Answer (score 1):

Your native aspect ratio is 8 : 5. If you are using Keynote for Mac to present, click wide when picking your template, which can be blank. When being chosen as wide, it sets the ratio to 16:9.